# rcapache2 extreme-configtest returns NOT OK but everything works

Tags: apache2

Running

```
rcapache2 extreme-configtest
```

on my Apache 2.2.12 on SLES11 SP2 returns

```
Syntax: NOT OK:
Syntax error on line 39 of /etc/apache2/somedirectory/ssl.somedomain.conf: SSLCertificateKeyFile:      file '/etc/apache2/ssldirectory/somekeyfile' does not exist or is empty
```

However /etc/apache2/ssldirectory/somekeyfile is there and is not empty.

```
rcapache2 configtest
```

works and the server starts without any errors show. No errors are logged and everything seems to work as expected. Bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering this myself if anybody else encounters this.

It is apparently expected behavior.

[Open Suse Documentation:](https://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/html/openSUSE_121/opensuse-reference/cha.apache2.html)

> **configtest or extreme-configtest**
>   Checks the syntax of the configuration files without affecting a running Web server. Because this check is forced every time the server is started, reloaded, or restarted, it is usually not necessary to run the test explicitly (if a configuration error is found, the Web server is not started, reloaded, or restarted). ***The extreme-configtest options start the Web server as user nobody and actually load the configuration, so more errors can be detected. Note that although the configuration is loaded, it is not possible to test the SSL setup because the SSL certificates cannot be read by nobody.***